# ListFragment does not accept my layout

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

According to this link: [ListFragment android developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html)

I want to set my custom layout for list, but it makes exceptions.

Here is the code:

```
public class ListFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if(fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null)
    {
        myListFragments list = new myListFragments();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();
    }
}

public static class myListFragments extends ListFragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.topoffers, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        List<OfferModel> offers = Global.getInstance().getOffers();
        List<OfferModel> topOffers = new ArrayList<OfferModel>(4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (offers.get(i).getOfferImage() == null)
                offers.get(i).setOfferImage(
                        downloadFile(offers.get(i).getOfferImageUrl()));
            topOffers.add(offers.get(i));
        }
        LazyAdapter adapter = new LazyAdapter(getActivity());
        adapter.setData(topOffers);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        setListShown(true);
    }

    public Bitmap downloadFile(String fileUrl) {
        URL myFileUrl = null;
        try {
            myFileUrl = new URL(fileUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}}
```

and my custom layout is `R.layout.topoffers`

Logcat:

```
 05-15 21:43:56.975: W/dalvikvm(218): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188) 
 05-15 21:43:56.975: E/AndroidRuntime(218): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.anddev.android.ikiwi/org.anddev.android.ikiwi.ListFragmentActivity}:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't be used with a custom content view 
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496) 
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512) 
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119) 
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363) 
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
    Can't be used with a custom content view 
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.setListShown(ListFragment.java:282)
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.setListShown(ListFragment.java:258)
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at org.anddev.android.ikiwi.ListFragmentActivity$myListFragments.onActivityCreated(ListFragmentActivity.java:57)
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:891)
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:505)
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3723) 
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
 05-15 21:43:56.995: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     ... 11 more 
 05-15 21:43:57.025: I/dalvikvm(218): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3 
 05-15 21:43:57.025: E/dalvikvm(218): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: This needs to be more specific than 'it makes exceptions'

Comment: right but i can not determine what is makes exception

Comment: Post your logcat showing the errors

Comment: Which is line 57 in ListFragmentActivity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like an issue that's been reported to Google already.

[Google Issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21742)

If this is indeed your issue, there's a couple of suggestions at the bottom of that page for fixing it (well, more making it work than fixing it).

Comment: thank you mr barak but in this suggestion he wrote in the short term I can only see overriding setEmptyText(String)::void and manually handling an empty view.. ..... how can i override setEmptyText function?

Comment: I believe you just delete the textview from your layout and in your onActivityCreated put `setEmptyText("Your emptyText message")`.  All the examples I've found show that being used before you create/set the adapter.

Comment: i did what you said to me but unfortunately it does not work, it still causes exception.

Comment: it working correctly with its default layout, but i still can not apply my layout forlist

Comment: i found what causes the problem but i can not solve it, the problem was in setListShown(boolean), when i delete it,it working correctly but i need it cuz i am implementing AsyncTaskLoader in loading data so  need to make the list hidden while loading data as sson as the progress bar can appear

Comment: okay thank you mr barak, i made fragment in my layout and give it my list fragment class .... many thanks for help

Comment: In my case, I just need to use `((TextView)getListView().getEmptyView()).setText(getString(R.string.empty_message));` instead of `setEmptyText(getString(R.string.empty_message))`. Credit for the Google issue link above.

Answer (score 23):

Create the layout file **list_content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/progressContainer"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:gravity="center">
        
        <ProgressBar style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text=""
                android:paddingTop="4dip"
                android:singleLine="true" />
            
    </LinearLayout>
        
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/listContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            
        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/internalEmpty"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </FrameLayout>
        
</FrameLayout>
```

Put this inside your **ListFragment** class:

```
public ListView mList;
boolean mListShown;
View mProgressContainer;
View mListContainer;

public void setListShown(boolean shown, boolean animate){
    if (mListShown == shown) {
        return;
    }
    mListShown = shown;
    if (shown) {
        if (animate) {
            mProgressContainer.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_out));
            mListContainer.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_in));
        }
        mProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mListContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        if (animate) {
            mProgressContainer.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_in));
            mListContainer.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_out));
        }
        mProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mListContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
public void setListShown(boolean shown){
    setListShown(shown, true);
}
public void setListShownNoAnimation(boolean shown) {
    setListShown(shown, false);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int INTERNAL_EMPTY_ID = 0x00ff0001;
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content, container, false);
    (root.findViewById(R.id.internalEmpty)).setId(INTERNAL_EMPTY_ID);
    mList = (ListView) root.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mListContainer =  root.findViewById(R.id.listContainer);
    mProgressContainer = root.findViewById(R.id.progressContainer);
    mListShown = true;
    return root;
}
```

Now you can use normally:

```
setListShown(boolean shown);
setListShown(boolean shown, boolean animate);
setListShownNoAnimation(boolean shown);
```

Source:

> http://source-android.frandroid.com/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ListFragment.java
>
> http://source-android.frandroid.com/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/list_content.xml

Answer (score 14):

This might be easier:
Create your layout as you would normally but don't add the list/empty/loading stuff. Then in your listfragment's onCreateView:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, container, false);
    parent.addView(v, 0);
    return parent;
}
```

Now you can use setListShown...

Comment: Just tried, it works. Best solution here! Much more simple than the other one as you keep all the methods from the SDK working.

Comment: Not only can you use setListShow(), but you get all the stock behavior  and look within the confines of your own greater layout. You may want to put a container within the parent and add the super view to it instead of to the parent itself.

Comment: This works, but as you can see [here](http://imgur.com/CCfqgmE), it causes your hierarchy to have two android:id/list.

Comment: +1 billion. I needed this solution for a different problem. I needed my own extra Views above and below the `ListView` used in `ListFragment`. I wanted to keep their `ListView` because I wanted to keep the progress bar/empty TextView functionality, but I needed some other Views in the fragment as well, not just a ListView. This method allowed me to drop their whole layout into my own. Took some playing around, but I was able to drop it into an empty FrameLayout in the middle of my LinearLayout. For whatever reason I couldn't directly add the view like you did without my layout looking wrong.

Comment: Also the **[Android doc's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) (_scroll to onCreateView()_)** suggest something similar, where you `<include>` the `list_content` layout (the resource ID for their default layout -can be found in the Android SDK's /res folder) in your XML. But that would only work with **API 11+** while this approach should be backward compatible with the Support-V4 library's `ListFragment` back to API 4. Kudos man, I wouldn't have thought of doing this.

Comment: " but don't add the list/empty/loading stuff. " - I need to show a specific string text in `@+id/empty` TextView. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 8):

Just replace the original ListView with your CustomListView Layout within the onCreateView method. Worked for me.

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout = super.onCreateView(inflater, container,
            savedInstanceState);
    ListView lv = (ListView) layout.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) lv.getParent();

    // Remove ListView and add CustomView  in its place
    int lvIndex = parent.indexOfChild(lv);
    parent.removeViewAt(lvIndex);
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.custom_list, container, false);
    parent.addView(mLinearLayout, lvIndex, lv.getLayoutParams());
    return layout;
}
```

Comment: Kudos for removing the unnecessary list view from the hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

Today I had the same issue. Looking the solution in Google, I found a post in a japanese blog. (http://blog.nkzn.net/entry/2012/06/14/160706).

For use `setListShown(boolean)` you must do first in your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in your ListFragment:

```
public class SampleListFragment extends ListFragment {

  /** ID for progressbar parent */
  private static final int INTERNAL_PROGRESS_CONTAINER_ID = 0x00ff0002;
  /** ID for listview parent */
  private static final int INTERNAL_LIST_CONTAINER_ID = 0x00ff0003;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_layout, container, false);

    // get you progressBar and his parent
    ProgressBar pBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(android.R.id.progress);
    LinearLayout pframe = (LinearLayout) pBar.getParent();
    pframe.setId(INTERNAL_PROGRESS_CONTAINER_ID);

    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    FrameLayout lFrame = (FrameLayout) listView.getParent();
    lFrame.setId(INTERNAL_LIST_CONTAINER_ID);    

    return view;
  } 
}
```

with this 2 ids numbers seted in his parents setListShown(boolean) will work without problems.

Comment: I read the ListFragment and this is the only way.. Thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that worked for me as well is just to put this line

```
<include layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
```

instead of your list view.

You are able to build your own content on top of it or surround it with some other views. For example, here is how my layout looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/default_view_padding"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="4">

    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnCounterBack"
            android:src="?attr/ic_previous"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:contentDescription="@null"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCounterLevel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/counter_categories"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/default_view_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_view_padding"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="?attr/dropShadowBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to change my empty text `TextView` properties and did this

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    // Swap the new cursor in. (The framework will take care of closing the
    // old cursor once we return)
    mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        setEmptyText(getString(R.string.no_users));
        TextView tvEmpty = (TextView) getListView().getEmptyView();
        tvEmpty.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
    }
    // The list should now be shown.
    if (isResumed()) {
        setListShown(true);
    } else {
        setListShownNoAnimation(true);
    }
}
```

Do not forget that if you try initializing `tvEmpty` before you call `setEmptyText("Empty")`, you'll run into a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    ((TextView)root.findViewById(0x00ff0001)).setText("some text");

    ListView list = (ListView) root.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    list.setEmptyView(root.findViewById(0x00ff0001));

    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but did not see this answer.

Inside `Fragment`:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
            final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_activity,
                container, false);  

        ListFragmentHelper.adaptView(view);

        return view;
    }
```

but **bear in mind** that in `fragment_list_activity.xml` you need to set  the IDs `android:id="@id/loading"`,  `android:id="@id/content"` and `android:id="@id/empty"` for your views!

Answer (score -2):

Try to remove `setListShown(true);`?

I had same problem, some time ago. 
It's seams that you cant use it if you have custom layout in `ListFragment`.

Comment: But I want to use setListSHown so I can Control whether the list is being displayed. I'd like to make it not displayed when waiting for the initial data to show in it. During this time an indeterminant progress indicator will be shown instead. The prgress indicator would be nice.