# How can style the ListView of a ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

I want to keep these methods:

```
setListShown(true);
setListShownNoAnimation(true);
```

but if I use

```
onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

to inflate the `Fragment` with a custom styled layout, the previous methods can't be used, and show this exception:

```
07-30 20:17:46.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1374): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't be used with a custom content view
07-30 20:17:46.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.setListShown(ListFragment.java:282)
07-30 20:17:46.937: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.setListShown(ListFragment.java:258)
```

So, what possible solution can be?

EDIT:

The `Fragment` uses a loader to populate its `ListView` from a database. So that's the reason why I want to keep those methods, they're needed here:

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);  
        if (isResumed()) {
            setListShown(true);
        } else {
            setListShownNoAnimation(true);
        }
    }
```

The easiest solution would be to make my own code based on the `ListFragment` source, an also add the progress widget to the layout to show the same effect. By now, I'll delete those lines as I've been told. If I do the modification I'll paste it here.

Comment: It's just a linearlayout with the listview, passing them the style attribute.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just replace the original `ListView` with your `CustomListView` Layout within the `onCreateView()`. Worked for me.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout = super.onCreateView(inflater, container,
            savedInstanceState);
    ListView lv = (ListView) layout.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) lv.getParent();

    // Remove ListView and add CustomView  in its place
    int lvIndex = parent.indexOfChild(lv);
    parent.removeViewAt(lvIndex);
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.custom_list, container, false);
    parent.addView(mLinearLayout, lvIndex, lv.getLayoutParams());
    return layout;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I've tried this solution and it works:

In the [support `ListFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) source code says,

> If you are overriding this method with your own custom content,
>   consider including the standard layout android.R.layout in your layout
>   file, so that you continue to retain all of the standard behavior of
>   ListFragment. In particular, this is currently the only way to have
>   the built-in indeterminant progress state be shown.

So, I've taken the list_content.xml and applied to the list my own style:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        style="@style/page_background">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/progressContainer"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:gravity="center">

        <ProgressBar style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:paddingTop="4dip"
                android:singleLine="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/listContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" 
                style="@style/rc_listview"/>
        <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Then made a fixed `ListFragment` copied from support source code.

- I renamed some ids to match the ones in the XML file.
- Delete its `onCreateView()`.

  ```
  public class FixedListFragment extends Fragment {

      final private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

      final private Runnable mRequestFocus = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              mList.focusableViewAvailable(mList);
          }
      };

      final private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mOnClickListener
              = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
              onListItemClick((ListView)parent, v, position, id);
          }
      };

      ListAdapter mAdapter;
      ListView mList;
      View mEmptyView;
      TextView mStandardEmptyView;
      View mProgressContainer;
      View mListContainer;
      CharSequence mEmptyText;
      boolean mListShown;

      public FixedListFragment() {
      }

      /**
       * Provide default implementation to return a simple list view.  Subclasses
       * can override to replace with their own layout.  If doing so, the
       * returned view hierarchy <em>must</em> have a ListView whose id
       * is {@link android.R.id#list android.R.id.list} and can optionally
       * have a sibling view id {@link android.R.id#empty android.R.id.empty}
       * that is to be shown when the list is empty.
       * 
       * <p>If you are overriding this method with your own custom content,
       * consider including the standard layout {@link android.R.layout#list_content}
       * in your layout file, so that you continue to retain all of the standard
       * behavior of ListFragment.  In particular, this is currently the only
       * way to have the built-in indeterminant progress state be shown.
       */

      /**
       * Attach to list view once the view hierarchy has been created.
       */
      @Override
      public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
          ensureList();
      }

      /**
       * Detach from list view.
       */
      public void onDestroyView() {
          mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRequestFocus);
          mList = null;
          mListShown = false;
          mEmptyView = mProgressContainer = mListContainer = null;
          mStandardEmptyView = null;
          super.onDestroyView();
      }

      /**
       * This method will be called when an item in the list is selected.
       * Subclasses should override. Subclasses can call
       * getListView().getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the
       * data associated with the selected item.
       *
       * @param l The ListView where the click happened
       * @param v The view that was clicked within the ListView
       * @param position The position of the view in the list
       * @param id The row id of the item that was clicked
       */
      public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
      }

      /**
       * Provide the cursor for the list view.
       */
      public void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
          boolean hadAdapter = mAdapter != null;
          mAdapter = adapter;
          if (mList != null) {
              mList.setAdapter(adapter);
              if (!mListShown && !hadAdapter) {
                  // The list was hidden, and previously didn't have an
                  // adapter.  It is now time to show it.
                  setListShown(true, getView().getWindowToken() != null);
              }
          }
      }

      /**
       * Set the currently selected list item to the specified
       * position with the adapter's data
       *
       * @param position
       */
      public void setSelection(int position) {
          ensureList();
          mList.setSelection(position);
      }

      /**
       * Get the position of the currently selected list item.
       */
      public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
          ensureList();
          return mList.getSelectedItemPosition();
      }

      /**
       * Get the cursor row ID of the currently selected list item.
       */
      public long getSelectedItemId() {
          ensureList();
          return mList.getSelectedItemId();
      }

      /**
       * Get the activity's list view widget.
       */
      public ListView getListView() {
          ensureList();
          return mList;
      }

      /**
       * The default content for a ListFragment has a TextView that can
       * be shown when the list is empty.  If you would like to have it
       * shown, call this method to supply the text it should use.
       */
      public void setEmptyText(CharSequence text) {
          ensureList();
          if (mStandardEmptyView == null) {
              throw new IllegalStateException("Can't be used with a custom content view");
          }
          mStandardEmptyView.setText(text);
          if (mEmptyText == null) {
              mList.setEmptyView(mStandardEmptyView);
          }
          mEmptyText = text;
      }

      /**
       * Control whether the list is being displayed.  You can make it not
       * displayed if you are waiting for the initial data to show in it.  During
       * this time an indeterminant progress indicator will be shown instead.
       * 
       * <p>Applications do not normally need to use this themselves.  The default
       * behavior of ListFragment is to start with the list not being shown, only
       * showing it once an adapter is given with {@link #setListAdapter(ListAdapter)}.
       * If the list at that point had not been shown, when it does get shown
       * it will be do without the user ever seeing the hidden state.
       * 
       * @param shown If true, the list view is shown; if false, the progress
       * indicator.  The initial value is true.
       */
      public void setListShown(boolean shown) {
          setListShown(shown, true);
      }

      /**
       * Like {@link #setListShown(boolean)}, but no animation is used when
       * transitioning from the previous state.
       */
      public void setListShownNoAnimation(boolean shown) {
          setListShown(shown, false);
      }

      /**
       * Control whether the list is being displayed.  You can make it not
       * displayed if you are waiting for the initial data to show in it.  During
       * this time an indeterminant progress indicator will be shown instead.
       * 
       * @param shown If true, the list view is shown; if false, the progress
       * indicator.  The initial value is true.
       * @param animate If true, an animation will be used to transition to the
       * new state.
       */
      private void setListShown(boolean shown, boolean animate) {
          ensureList();
          if (mProgressContainer == null) {
              throw new IllegalStateException("Can't be used with a custom content view");
          }
          if (mListShown == shown) {
              return;
          }
          mListShown = shown;
          if (shown) {
              if (animate) {
                  mProgressContainer.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                          getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_out));
                  mListContainer.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                          getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_in));
              } else {
                  mProgressContainer.clearAnimation();
                  mListContainer.clearAnimation();
              }
              mProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              mListContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          } else {
              if (animate) {
                  mProgressContainer.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                          getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_in));
                  mListContainer.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                          getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_out));
              } else {
                  mProgressContainer.clearAnimation();
                  mListContainer.clearAnimation();
              }
              mProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              mListContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }
      }

      /**
       * Get the ListAdapter associated with this activity's ListView.
       */
      public ListAdapter getListAdapter() {
          return mAdapter;
      }

      private void ensureList() {
          if (mList != null) {
              return;
          }
          View root = getView();
          if (root == null) {
              throw new IllegalStateException("Content view not yet created");
          }
          if (root instanceof ListView) {
              mList = (ListView)root;
          } else {
              mStandardEmptyView = (TextView)root.findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
              if (mStandardEmptyView == null) {
                  mEmptyView = root.findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
              } else {
                  mStandardEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              }
              mProgressContainer = root.findViewById(R.id.progressContainer);
              mListContainer = root.findViewById(R.id.listContainer);
              View rawListView = root.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
              if (!(rawListView instanceof ListView)) {
                  if (rawListView == null) {
                      throw new RuntimeException(
                              "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is " +
                              "'android.R.id.list'");
                  }
                  throw new RuntimeException(
                          "Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' "
                          + "that is not a ListView class");
              }
              mList = (ListView)rawListView;
              if (mEmptyView != null) {
                  mList.setEmptyView(mEmptyView);
              } else if (mEmptyText != null) {
                  mStandardEmptyView.setText(mEmptyText);
                  mList.setEmptyView(mStandardEmptyView);
              }
          }
          mListShown = true;
          mList.setOnItemClickListener(mOnClickListener);
          if (mAdapter != null) {
              ListAdapter adapter = mAdapter;
              mAdapter = null;
              setListAdapter(adapter);
          } else {
              // We are starting without an adapter, so assume we won't
              // have our data right away and start with the progress indicator.
              if (mProgressContainer != null) {
                  setListShown(false, false);
              }
          }
          mHandler.post(mRequestFocus);
      }   
  }
  ```

After that, everything goes perfect. 
Just inflate this list_content.xml when creating the `Fragment`.

```
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: I am getting a nullpointerexception at the setListAdapter() in onActivityCreated. Any pointers

Comment: @codingcrow sorry to hear that, but I've revised all this in my application and I get no errors, maybe something else...

Comment: Did you needed to create the new code? Was't the inflate with the custom and the standard layout merged enough? I am asking because I am comparing your answer with [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608624/listfragment-does-not-accept-my-layout).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that worked for me as well is just to put this line

```
<include layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
```

instead of your ListView.

You are able to build your own content on top of it or surround it with some other views. For example, here is how my layout looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/default_view_padding"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="4">

    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnCounterBack"
            android:src="?attr/ic_previous"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:contentDescription="@null"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCounterLevel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/counter_categories"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/default_view_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_view_padding"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="?attr/dropShadowBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

`setListShown(true);` and `setListShownNoAnimation(true);` are not supported by the support package and only available in Api Level 11+. You either have to give up the support of <= Api Level 10 (bad choice) or remove the lines.

If I understand the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) correctly you do not have to set them anyways because `true` is the default value

Comment: Well, I've to find other way because I need those for the loader. I've edited the question with that info.

Comment: I totally misunderstood the error message. The methods are supported, but not with a custom content vie. Maybe a look at the [source code](http://bit.ly/PgVG6d) helps

Comment: Yes, I'll do that maybe I take some part of the source. Thank you.