# ListFragment hide indeterminant progress indicator when using custom view

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I currently have a ListFragment from which I am returning a custom ListView from the `OnCreateView()` (included below).

The issue I have is when there are only a few items in the view, you can see the progress indicator in the background. `setListShown(true)` hides the progress indicator, but when returning a custom view it results in an IllegalStateException.

Any ideas on a way to hide the progress indicator?

```
@Override
public ListView onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ListView lv = new ListView(this.getActivity());
    lv.setId(android.R.id.list);
    lv.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
    lv.setStackFromBottom(true);

    return lv;
}
```

EDIT: I've also tried inflating the view, but it returns the same IllegalStateException.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    setListShown(true);
}

@Override
public ListView onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ListView lv = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_fragment, container, false);
    lv.setId(android.R.id.list);

    return lv;
}

08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.wisc.ACHESS/edu.wisc.ACHESS.ChatMessageActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't be used with a custom content view
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't be used with a custom content view
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.setListShown(ListFragment.java:282)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.setListShown(ListFragment.java:258)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at edu.wisc.ACHESS.fragments.ChatFragment.onViewCreated(ChatFragment.java:19)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:523)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1163)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5018)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2032)
08-02 12:58:19.552: E/AndroidRuntime(27844):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: I had that problem, check my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608624/list-fragment-does-not-accept-my-layout/12504097#12504097

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [ListFragment does not accept my layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608624/list-fragment-does-not-accept-my-layout)

Seems like this is a bug on Google's end. There are a few suggestions here:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21742

Comment: Looks like a bug or maybe a feature, but recompiling the compatibility library from source with 'mProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);' changed to 'mProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE;' took care of it...

Answer (score -1):

You can hide the indicator by

```
getView().findViewById(16711682).setVisibility(View.GONE);
//16711682 is the variable mProgressContainer's id.
```

Put it after the view initialized, like in `onActivityCreated` method