# "Automatic" ProgressDialog won't dismiss

Tags: android, progressdialog

When i start my app the first activity loads data from an external source with an AsyncTask. A ProgressDialog with the text "Loading..." gets diaplayed, but when the news items fragment loads the dialog is still visible on top of the fragment.

I invoke another ProgressDialog in the AsyncTask (which also gets displayed), but it seems to be a different one, because when I comment it out the aforementioned AsyncTask the other ProgressBar still overlays the rendered fragment.

Most questions here are related to actually invoked ProgressBars and i don't instantiate another one anywhere.

Thanks

**Update: with accepted answer**

activity_news.xml: Had to remove the ListView element, since referencing Fragment is a ListFragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

NewsListFragment.java:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    context = getActivity();
    adpt = new NewsArrayAdapter(new ArrayList<NewsItem>(), context);
    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setAdapter(adpt);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new NewsItemOnClickListener());
    startNewAsyncTask();
}

@Override
public void taskFinished(List<NewsItem> result) {
    setListShown(true);
    dialog.dismiss();
    adpt.setItemList(result);
    adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

That solved it!

Comment: show some code. We understand code more than we understand language

Comment: I've added the task, the fragment and the relevant activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that inside the task in onPostExecute() you can call "dialog.dismiss()". But first check if dialog != null.

**Edit:**
As a suggestion if you are using asyncTask you can define an Handler and pass it to the task. When the task finishes you can pass the result to the handler that set the adapter of the list with result. Is mostly related to separation of concerns.

**Edit 2:**
I found out that you can use that when you finished loading data:

```
setListShown(true);
```

Hope it will solve the issue :D

**Edit 3:**
I have another suggestion. In your ListFragment you are getting the listview from the Activity layout. Conceptually is kinda wrong. Remove the listview from your activity layout and inside your ListFragment simply use getListview(). This kind of fragment provides a listview that's why it is called like that.

Comment: If i don't instantiate the ProgressDialog at all it still shows the loading spinner as seen in the screenshot. It's not even a dialog, it's just the spinner... So unfortunately that's not it

Comment: Are you sure is not part of your activity layout? Where is it defined the wheel?

Comment: It isn't defined anywhere. I've searched all the code from within TextMate for "Loading..." and nothing came up

Comment: Can you post your activity layout?

Comment: But also content_frame and activity_news

Comment: Reading this answer seems that there is a bug in Android ListFragment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781860/listfragment-hide-indeterminant-progress-indicator-when-using-custom-view.

Comment: My suggestion is to replace your List fragment with a normal fragment which contains a Listview in its layout and the only thing you have to change is referencing the listview from the xml.

Comment: setListShown() will not work if you use custom layout. However, I agree that if your layout contains just a ListView then it's better to not use it. Instead use built-in layout provided by ListFragment or ListActivity classes. Then setListShow() will work and show busy indicator.

Comment: Putting setListShown(true) in taskFinished() did the trick. Sometimes it can be zo easy! I'll update both my code and the question implementing your third suggestion as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are doing big mistake keeping strong reference to Activity inside AsyncTask. Secondly, this line `new WeakReference<NewsAsyncTask>(asyncTask);` do nothing for you.

So this how I would do it:

- Introduce callback interface in your `AsyncTask`
- Create reference to callback through `WeakReference`
- Remove dependency to Adapter, Context and Dialog

**AsyncTask**

```
public class NewsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<NewsItem>> {
    private final WeakReference<NewsTaskCallback> weakCallback;

    public interface NewsTaskCallback {
        void taskStarted();
        void taskFinished(List<NewsItem> result);
        void taskCancelled();
    }

    public NewsAsyncTask(NewsTaskCallback callback) {
        weakCallback = new WeakReference<NewsTaskCallback>(callback);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        NewsTaskCallback c = weakCallback.get();
        if (c != null) {
            c.taskCancelled();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        NewsTaskCallback c = weakCallback.get();
        if (c != null) {
            c.taskStarted();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<NewsItem> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        NewsTaskCallback c = weakCallback.get();
        if (c != null) {
            c.taskFinished(result);
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

Now, in your fragment do the following:

- Implement `NewsTaskCallback`
- Handle showing and hiding Dialog in callback methods
- Handle adapter updates in taskFinished()
- move starting task to the end of `onActivityCreated()`

**Fragment**

```
public class NewsListFragment extends ListFragment implements NewsTaskCallback {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private NewsArrayAdapter adpt;
    private NewsAsyncTask asyncTask;
    private static final String URL = "http://lisateam.lisa-is.nl/XmlServices_v2/News/GetClubNews.aspx";

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        adpt = new NewsArrayAdapter(new ArrayList<NewsItem>(), context);
        ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setAdapter(adpt);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new NewsItemOnClickListener());
        startNewAsyncTask();
    }

    @Override
    public void taskStarted() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Een moment geduld...", "De nieuwsberichten worden geladen");
    }

    @Override
    public void taskFinished(List<NewsItem> result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        adpt.setItemList(result);
        adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void taskCancelled() {
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    ....

    private void startNewAsyncTask() {
        if (asyncTask != null) {
            asyncTask.cancel(false);
            asyncTask = null;
        }
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        asyncTask = new NewsAsyncTask(this);
        asyncTask.execute(URL);
    }
}
```

With above code you will get some benefits:

- you can call startNewAsyncTask() as many times as you wish, currently running task will be properly finished before new task start
- there will be ONLY one dialog at a time, you should no longer see duplicates
- Activity(with your fragment) can be destroyed while AsyncTask is running, now it will be handled thanks to WeakReference used properly.

Comment: I've implemented your suggestions but the second spinner is still showing. I'll update my question with a screenshot

Comment: Please also update the code with latest changes. I have also updated my answer adding additional dismiss() call when new AsyncTask is starting. Did you try to log all dialog related events? If not, please do so.