# Android ListFragment with custom CursorAdapter not showing data

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment, android-cursoradapter

So basically I have a ListFragment setup like this

```
public class ObavijestiFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
private View mApiError;
private ObavijestiAdapter mAdapter;
private static String TAG="ObavijestiFragment";

public static ObavijestiFragment newInstance() {
    return new ObavijestiFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_obavijesti, container, false);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mApiError = view.findViewById(R.id.api_error);
}
```

Also, I implemented `onActivityCreated` and `onLoadFinished` like this

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Activity activity = getActivity();

    if (!activity.isFinishing()) {
        Loader loader = getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(Config.OBAVIJESTI_CURSOR_ID);

        mAdapter = new ObavijestiAdapter(activity, null, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        if (loader != null && !loader.isReset()) {
            getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(Config.OBAVIJESTI_CURSOR_ID, null, this);
        } else {
            getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(Config.OBAVIJESTI_CURSOR_ID, null, this);
        }
    }
}

 public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader,Cursor cursor) {
    if(mAdapter!=null && cursor!=null)
        mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}
```

My cursor in onLoadFinished has 4 rows of data but non of this rows are shown in my ListView. Can somebody help me with this?? Also `bindView` or `newView` in my custom adapter that extends `CursorAdapter` are newer reached. Below is this Adapter.

```
public class ObavijestiAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
private Cursor mCursor;
private Context mContext;
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView hTextNaslov;
    public TextView hTextOpis;
    public ImageView hImage;
}
public ObavijestiAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();

    //TODO: REMOVE AFTER IMPLEMENTING REAL IMAGE
    int w = 24, h = 24;
    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // see other conf types
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
    //END REMOVE

    holder.hImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    holder.hTextNaslov.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataContract.Obavijesti.OBAVIJESTI_NASLOV)));
    holder.hTextOpis.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataContract.Obavijesti.OBAVIJESTI_OPIS)));
}


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_obavijesti_row,parent,false);

    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.hTextOpis = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.obOpis);
    holder.hTextNaslov = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.obNaslov);
    holder.hImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.oblist_image);
    view.setTag(holder);
    return view;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I tryed with SimpleCursorAdapter and just one TextView like this:

```
String[] from = new String[] {DataContract.Obavijesti.OBAVIJESTI_NASLOV};
    int[]  to = new int[] { R.id.obNaslov };

    sAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.fragment_obavijesti_row, null, from,to , 0);
    setListAdapter(sAdapter);

    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

but no luck. Again in, `onLoadFinished` the cursor.getCount()=4 and this is the right number

**UPDATE 2:**
So, after putting  `ListView lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.obList);` and `lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);` instead of `setListAdapter` everything is ok... But now I have another problem. I am expecting main activity (that includes support ActionBar) to load first and after that a progress bar to show when data in the ListView is loading. This is why I implemented CursorLoader in the first place. I tried to put `Thread.sleep(9000);` in `onCreateLoader` for testing, but whole activity screen loades at the same time, so the whole UI is stopped for 9 seconds. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: did you dump the Cursor to the logcat to be sure the Cursor has data?

Comment: Yes... cursor.getCount()=4 in onLoadFinished, and that is exactly what I need to get

Comment: and bindView is never called?

Comment: no... and newView also

Comment: to isolate the problem try SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: I updated my question, but no luck with SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: step into swapCursor with a debugger and see what happens inside

Comment: I might try `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in your `onLoadFinished()`

Comment: for what I can see, the problem seems to be related that you are using setListAdapter(mAdapter); and that method sets the adapter but for the internal listview on the ListFragment, however you are inflating your own custom layout (try removing your custom layout and check if it shows, if it does try placing those extra views you are using on that layout into another fragment so you have nested or try setting the internal id for the listview)

Comment: `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` didn't help...

Comment: @alensp Raykut is right, i missed you are using setListAdapter instead of ListView.setAdapter

Comment: Now I am confused... In onCreateView I have `View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_obavijesti, container, false);` In this XML is the base listView with id `@id/android:list`, and in `R.layout.fragment_obavijesti_row` a my custom list items... What I need to call to to set the adapter??

Comment: ok try to debug setListAdapter, make sure mList is not null, if it is null your list will always be empty

Comment: Sorry, I am tired now, so after some looking at the code I realised what are you saying. So I just edited XML and added @+id/obList to ListView and added `ListView lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.obList);` and `lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);` instead of `setListAdapter` in original code and everything works now... Thanks @pskink and @Raykud for all the help

Comment: so extend Fragment, extending ListFragment and providing own ListView is not a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your second question don't sleep in `onCreateLoader`, that's supposed to be the fast part. Sleep in `onLoadFinished` to represent it taking a while to load the data.

Comment: I moved `onCreateLoader` to `onLoadFinished` but it seams that this is a mayor problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608624/listfragment-does-not-accept-my-layout... I tryed every solution from this post, and nothing works... I reverted to using `setListAdapter(mAdapter)` and standard `@android:id/list` and my data is now shown. But the whole activity is displayed when everything is fully loaded, and not like it is expected to work

Comment: Ah, you were thinking that it would load the first ones and then the others later. The cursor adapter can't know when you've loaded the relevant ones. If you want to load the first stuff and load the rest in the background you'll have to create your own adapter to do that.

Comment: No. The data needs to load all at once but in background. The problem is with layout. I am expecting it to work like this [PICTURE](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/01646ccc7f29e4fcb95f8f99ac5e5e3cf14345b6/687474703a2f2f6934342e74696e797069632e636f6d2f333466666e63782e706e67) The top toolbar and navdrawer are generate and until the listview data is loaded it needs to show progress bar. If there is no data, show "no data"... I think that this is the default behavior of ListFragment, but in my case, it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't see anything in the cursor loader that would cause it to hang. Can you put up your activity maybe it's something in there.

Comment: Is it possible, thate Threed.sleep() hangs the main activity?? If so, how can I test "long loading" of the data?

Comment: Oh... sorry I didn't think about what I was saying. To test long loading of the data you add the sleep to `loadInBackground()` in your cursor loader. That's the thing that's in another thread.